# making POST requests in laravel

Tags: laravel

I know this is a valid post request in laravel:

```
{!! Form::open(['action' => 'PagesController@store', 'method' =>'POST']) !!}

{{ Form::label('a', 'Water Requirements: ') }} 
{{ Form::radio('water_type', '1to2days') }} {{ Form::label('a', '1 to 2 days') }}  
{{ Form::radio('water_type', '2to3days') }} {{ Form::label('name', '2 to 3 days') }} 
{{ Form::radio('water_type', '6to7days') }} {{ Form::label('name', '6 to 7 days') }}
{{Form::submit('Filter', ['class'=>'btn bt-primary', 'name' => 'submitbutton'])}}
{{Form::submit('Clear', ['class'=>'btn bt-primary', 'name' => 'submitbutton'])}}


{!! Form::close() !!}
```

And i can access the request via `$request->input('water_type')` etc in my controller.

Now I want to make a post request in the following code:

```
{!! Form::open(['action' => 'PagesController@store', 'method' =>'POST']) !!}

<div align="center" class="container">
    <table id="myTable">
        <tr id="initialRow" class="select_row">
        <td>  
            <select id = "soflow" class="select1">
            <option>Select an option</option>
            <option>yes</option>
            <option>no</option>
            </select>
            <select id = "soflow" class="select2">
                <option>Select an option</option>

            </select>

        </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
{{Form::submit('Filter', ['class'=>'button', 'name' => 'submitbutton'])}}
{{Form::submit('Clear', ['class'=>'btn bt-primary', 'name' => 'submitbutton'])}}


{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Doing this, I am only able to access `$request->submitbutton` since it is within `Form` tags. Is there any way I can also get the values of the selected options from drop-downs, using the current basic html `<select>`. I know it is possible to do this using `Form::select` but I am not interested in that solution for now.

Comment: add name to select

Comment: <select name="soflow" id = "soflow" class="select1"> </select> and then you can access it as the following

Comment: $request->soflow

Comment: oh couldn't think of that. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Mention 'name' attribute for select.